# check if a list of string is in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I need to check if the whole list of strings is in a column.
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
frame=["foo", "abc", "story"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo abc', 'foobar abc', 'bar32', 'abc 45'], 'col2': ['story', 'epic', 'story', 'baz']}) 
df["Concat"] = df["col1"] +' '+ df["col2"]
df2=df[df['Concat'].apply(lambda x: set(frame).issubset(x))]
print(df2)
```

this is the output:

```
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, Concat]
Index: []
```

but if I work with letters as shows in the code below, I get the desired output

```
import pandas as pd
frame=["f", "a", "s"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo abc', 'foobar abc', 'bar32', 'abc 45'], 'col2': ['story', 'epic', 'story', 'baz']}) 
df["Concat"] = df["col1"] +' '+ df["col2"]
df2=df[df['Concat'].apply(lambda x: set(frame).issubset(x))]
print('\n',df2)
```

desired output:

```
       col1   col2         Concat
0  foo abc  story  foo abc story
```

how can I work with strings, not letters and still get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change `x` to `x.split()` on line 5

```
import pandas as pd
frame=["foo", "abc", "story"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo abc', 'foobar abc', 'bar32', 'abc 45'], 'col2': ['story', 'epic', 'story', 'baz']}) 
df["Concat"] = df["col1"] +' '+ df["col2"]
df2=df[df['Concat'].apply(lambda x: set(frame).issubset(x.split()))]
print(df2)
```

Right now you're testing if a set of words is a subset of a string. This operation is not well-defined, because it is ambiguous how to interpret a string as a set - is a string a set of characters or a set of words? By default python interprets strings as a set of characters because it has no knowledge of natural language conventions like 'words are separated by spaces'. `x.split()` resolves this ambiguity by splitting words on whitespace, which I assume is what you want

Answer (score 1):

In the first code sample you are comparing a set of 3 elements `frame` with every string present in each row `x` which is converted to a set of 1 element only: `issubset` returns `False` for every row since 3 elements cannot be subset of 1 element.

If you split `x` before calling `apply` you will test if `frame` is subset of a list of elements:

```
df['Concat'].str.split().apply(lambda x: set(frame).issubset(x))
```